# Load coordinates to Google Maps from localstorage with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

When a user clicks a button, it will keep refreshing their location and pushing it to an array and in the end when the user clicks another button,it should show their path from the time the start button was clicked:

```
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(recordtrip, 5000);

function recordtrip(){
if (navigator.geolocation) {        
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    x = position;

    triplog.push(new google.maps.LatLng(x.coords.latitude,x.coords.longitude));

$('#stoptrip').click(function(){
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);

});
});
$('#showtrip').click(function(){
var lenoftrip = triplog.length - 1 ;

var mapProp = {
  center:triplog[lenoftrip],
  zoom:20,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:triplog[lenoftrip],
  });

marker.setMap(map);
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:triplog,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2
  });

flightPath.setMap(map);

});
```

It works well before saving to localstorage, but after saving and loading it,it doesn't work anymore.
I realized then when i call the array from localstorage,it removes the `new google.maps.LatLng`.
This is the saving function:

```
$('#savetrip').click(function(){
localStorage.setItem(titleoftrip,JSON.stringify(triplog));
alert("Saved!");
triplog = [];
}
```

How do you fix this?

Comment: Where are you storing your data in local storage? I believe values would be cast to string when you store things into localstorage, even true/false becomes "true"/"false". If that is the case, then you should use `JSON.parse()` method to parses your object from string back into object.

Comment: @kaho sorry! I added it to the question and I am parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the answer is a bit confusing but I solved the problem I was having:
I realised that the problem was that it was giving errors while parsing the data.I think the reason for this was that I was saving the array `triplog` in which each piece of data stored was `new google.maps.LatLng(x.coords.latitude,x.coords.longitude)`.
So i created a new array `triplogsave` which stored only `x.coords.latitude,x.coords.longitude` and saved that to localStorage and when I called that and parsed it, it worked without any errors.
the edited code is:

```
var triplog =[];
var triplogsave = [];
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(recordtrip, 5000);

function recordtrip(){
if (navigator.geolocation) {        
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    x = position;

    triplog.push(new google.maps.LatLng(x.coords.latitude,x.coords.longitude));
triplogsave.push(x.coords.latitude,x.coords.longitude);

$('#stoptrip').click(function(){
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);

});
});
$('#showtrip').click(function(){
var lenoftrip = triplog.length - 1 ;

var mapProp = {
  center:triplog[lenoftrip],
  zoom:20,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:triplog[lenoftrip],
  });

marker.setMap(map);
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:triplog,
  strokeColor:"#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity:0.8,
  strokeWeight:2
  });

flightPath.setMap(map);

});

$('#savetrip').click(function(){
localStorage.setItem(titleoftrip,JSON.stringify(triplog));
alert("Saved!");
triplog = [];
}
```

so after saving and loading,it loads triologsave instead of triplog,parses it and loads that array into a google map.